# How to use session-global variables of type collection in oracle

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql, package, scope

I have a package which declares a collection of type table of some database table's %rowtype. It also declares a function to populate the package-level variable with some data. I can now print the data with dbms_output, seems fine.

But when I use the package-level variable in some sql I get the following error:

```
ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete
ORA-06512: at "TESTDB.SESSIONGLOBALS", line 17
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

Here is my code:

**create some dummy data:**

```
drop table "TESTDATA";
/
CREATE TABLE "TESTDATA" 
(   "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
);
/   
insert into "TESTDATA" (id, name, status) values (1, 'Hans Wurst', 'J');
insert into "TESTDATA" (id, name, status) values (2, 'Hans-Werner', 'N');
insert into "TESTDATA" (id, name, status) values (3, 'Hildegard v. Bingen', 'J');
/
```

**now create the package:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE SESSIONGLOBALS AS 
  type t_testdata is table of testdata%rowtype;
  v_data t_testdata := t_testdata();
  function load_testdata return t_testdata;

END SESSIONGLOBALS;
```

**and the package body:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY SESSIONGLOBALS AS
  function load_testdata return t_testdata AS
    v_sql varchar2(500);
  BEGIN
    if SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data.count = 0 
    then
      v_sql := 'select * from testdata';
      execute immediate v_sql 
      bulk collect into SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data;

      dbms_output.put_line('data count:');
      dbms_output.put_line(SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data.count);

    end if; -- SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data.count = 0 

    -- ******************************
    -- this line throws the error
    insert into testdata select * from table(SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data);
    -- ******************************

    return SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data;
  END load_testdata;

END SESSIONGLOBALS;
```

**execute the sample:**

```
DECLARE
  v_Return SESSIONGLOBALS.T_TESTDATA;
BEGIN
    v_Return := SESSIONGLOBALS.LOAD_TESTDATA();
    dbms_output.put_line('data count (direct access):');
    dbms_output.put_line(SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data.count);
    dbms_output.put_line('data count (return value of function):');
    dbms_output.put_line(v_Return.count);
END;
```

If the line marked above is commented out i get the expected result.

So can anyone tell me why the exception stated above occurs?

BTW: it is **absolutely nessecary** for me to execute the statement which populates the collection with data as dynamic sql because the tablename is not known at compiletime. (v_sql := 'select * from testdata';)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is to use **pipelined** functions in the package

see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm#CHDJEGHC ( => section **Pipelining Between PL/SQL Table Functions** does the trick).

my package looks like this now (please take the table script from my question):

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE SESSIONGLOBALS AS 
  v_force_refresh boolean;
  function set_force_refresh return boolean;

  type t_testdata is table of testdata%rowtype;
  v_data t_testdata;
  function load_testdata return t_testdata;
  function get_testdata return t_testdata pipelined;
END SESSIONGLOBALS;
/

create or replace 
PACKAGE BODY SESSIONGLOBALS AS
  function set_force_refresh return boolean as
  begin
    SESSIONGLOBALS.v_force_refresh := true;
    return true;
  end set_force_refresh;

  function load_testdata return t_testdata AS
    v_sql varchar2(500);
    v_i number(10);
  BEGIN
    if SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data is null then
      SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data := SESSIONGLOBALS.t_testdata();
    end if;

    if SESSIONGLOBALS.v_force_refresh = true then
      SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data.delete;
    end if;

    if SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data.count = 0 
    then
      v_sql := 'select * from testdata';
      execute immediate v_sql 
      bulk collect into SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data;

    end if; -- SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data.count = 0 

    return SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data;
  END load_testdata;

  function get_testdata return t_testdata pipelined AS
    v_local_data SESSIONGLOBALS.t_testdata := SESSIONGLOBALS.load_testdata();
  begin
    if v_local_data.count > 0 then
      for i in v_local_data.first .. v_local_data.last
      loop
        pipe row(v_local_data(i));
      end loop;
    end if;
  end get_testdata;

END SESSIONGLOBALS;
/
```

now i can do a select in sql like this:

```
select * from table(SESSIONGLOBALS.get_testdata());
```

and my data collection is only populated once.
nevertheless it is quite not comparable with a simple
    select * from testdata;
from a performace point of view but i'll try out this concept for some more complicated use cases. the goal is to avoid doing some really huge *select* statements involving lots of tables distributed among several schemas (english plural for schema...?).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you use does not work:

```
insert into testdata select * from table(SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data); -- does not work
```

You have to use something like that:

```
forall i in 1..v_data.count
  INSERT INTO testdata VALUES (SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data(i).id,
                               SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data(i).name,
                               SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data(i).status);
```

(which actually duplicates the rows in the table)

Comment: Thanks for the edit... But I wanted to show that SESSIONGLOBALS can be omitted (But that can still be seen from the `1..v_data.count`)

Comment: i usually keep the package name for package-level variables (functions/procedures) to visualize the variable scope

Answer (score 1):

Package-level types cannot be used in SQL.  Even if your SQL is called from within a package, it still can't see that package's types.

I'm not sure how you got that error message, when I compiled the package I got this error, which gives a good hint at the problem:

```
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
```

---

To fix this problem, create a type and a nested table of that type:

```
create or replace type t_testdata_rec is object
(
    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
);

create or replace type t_testdata as table of t_testdata_rec;
/
```

The dynamic SQL to populate the package variable gets more complicated:

```
  execute immediate
  'select cast(collect(t_testdata_rec(id, name, status)) as t_testdata)
  from testdata ' into SESSIONGLOBALS.v_data;
```

But now the insert will work as-is.

Comment: +1 cz PLS-00642 put me on the right question: how to use package-level collections in sql? ill post the solution i've found.